# Java program wont stop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an array with the size of n which is filled with the numbers 1..n.

I need to sum this array using m threads by each time taking two elements, sum them up and inserting the sum back to the array.

Here is what I tried to do.

The synchronized part first

```
public class MultiThreadedSum {

    private ArrayBuffer ArrayBufferInst;
    private int Sum;
    private boolean Flag, StopFlag;

    public MultiThreadedSum(ArrayBuffer ArrayBufferInst) {
        this.ArrayBufferInst = ArrayBufferInst;
        Sum = 0;
        Flag = false;
        StopFlag = false;
    }

    public synchronized void Sum2Elements() {
        while(Flag){
            try {wait();}
            catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
        Flag = true;
        if (StopFlag) {
            notifyAll();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Removing and adding 2 elements.");
        Sum = ArrayBufferInst.Sum2Elements();
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void InsertElement() {

        while(!Flag){
            try {wait();}
            catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
        Flag = false;
        if (StopFlag) {
            notifyAll();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Inserting the sum.");
        ArrayBufferInst.InsertElement(Sum);
        if (ArrayBufferInst.RetunrSize() == 1) {
            StopFlag = true;
        }
        System.out.println(ArrayBufferInst);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public boolean ReturnStopFlag(){
        return StopFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ArrayBufferInst.toString();
    }
}
```

I've splitted the m threads to 2 groups, half of them will do the summarization and half will do the adding using wait and notify.

```
public class Sum2ElementsThread implements Runnable{
    private MultiThreadedSum MultiThreadedSumInst;    
    public Sum2ElementsThread( MultiThreadedSum MultiThreadedSumInst){
        this.MultiThreadedSumInst = MultiThreadedSumInst;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!MultiThreadedSumInst.ReturnStopFlag())
            MultiThreadedSumInst.Sum2Elements();
    }
}

public class InsertThread implements Runnable{
    private MultiThreadedSum MultiThreadedSumInst;    
    public InsertThread( MultiThreadedSum MultiThreadedSumInst) {
        this.MultiThreadedSumInst = MultiThreadedSumInst;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!MultiThreadedSumInst.ReturnStopFlag())  {
            MultiThreadedSumInst.InsertElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is part of the main:

```
ArrayBufferInst = new ArrayBuffer(n);

System.out.println("The Array");
System.out.println(ArrayBufferInst);

MultiThreadedSumInst = new MultiThreadedSum(ArrayBufferInst);

ExecutorService Threads = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

for (i = 0; i < m/2; i++)
    Threads.execute( new Sum2ElementsThread(MultiThreadedSumInst) );
for (; i < m; i++)
    Threads.execute( new InsertThread(MultiThreadedSumInst) );
Threads.shutdown();
while(!MultiThreadedSumInst.ReturnStopFlag()){}
System.out.println("The sum of the array is " + MultiThreadedSumInst);
```

And the buffer

```
public class ArrayBuffer {
    private ArrayList<Integer> ArrayBufferInst;
    public ArrayBuffer(int SizeOfBuffer){
        int i;
        ArrayBufferInst = new ArrayList<>(SizeOfBuffer);
        for (i = 0; i < SizeOfBuffer; i++){
            ArrayBufferInst.add(i, i+1);
        }
    }

    public int Sum2Elements(){
        if (ArrayBufferInst.size() < 2){
            return -1;
        }
        return ArrayBufferInst.remove(0) + ArrayBufferInst.remove(0);
    }

    public void InsertElement(int Elem) {
        ArrayBufferInst.add(Elem);
    }
    public int RetunrSize(){
        return ArrayBufferInst.size();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ArrayBufferInst.toString();
    }
}
```

My question is about the end of the main, sometimes the program stop, sometime it doesn't, I know all the threads are exiting the run method because I checked that.

Sometimes I see the `The sum of the array is` message, sometimes I don't.

Comment: Just too much code to review for this issue. you must reduce unnecessary code so that it becomes more easy to answer.

Comment: @Siddharth Your second comment is completely uncalled for. Flagged.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
public synchronized void Sum2Elements() {
    while(Flag){
        try {wait();}
        catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }
    Flag = true;
    // rest of method omitted here
}
```

When this part of the program is executed for the first time `Flag` is false and the loop is ignored. All subsequent executions of this method will result in a deadlock since this is the only place where you set `Flag` to false.

Not even interrupting will work, since you have no `break` in your loop and after the interruption you just go on to the next cycle and `wait()` forever.

Oh and read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) - Java is not c#

Comment: Well, I have checked all threads are finishing there jobs and I believe they do. I believe once it started, the first thread will pass the while, then set flag to true, blocking all the other threads, meanwhile in InsertElement all the threads are already waiting. When this thread reaches notifyAll() it will allow one of the threads to do the same thing in InsertElement. Am I wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is really a very long code for you task.

Maybe i can propose a different sollution. 
You can just split array for m parts (m - is a number of threads) - and each thread would sum it`s own part. When summing is over in each Thread - just sum all part results.

Or maybe i didnt get your task correctly. Specify more details please (the full task).

Comment: I agree but this is what they wanted in the assignment, Thanks.